# Если множественного наследования не существует, то это что?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Является ли это множественным наследованием? Если нет, то что это? 
Странный синтаксис, я до этого с таким не сталкивался.

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, IDbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IQueryable, IInternalSetAdapter where TEntity : class
```

Comment: От интерфейсов не наследуются, их реализуют

Comment: я еще последние строки не особо понял. получается, класс TEntity наследуется от другого класса? @AlexF

Comment: @penancewarrior, `TEntity` - ни от чего не наследуется, просто указано, что это должен быть класс, а не струтура

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наследование, действительно, может быть только от одного базового класса, в вашем случае это `DbQuery`. Все остальные аргументы в списке это интерфейсы, которые обязан реализовывать класс, их может быть сколько угодно. В именовании интерфейсов принято в начале приписывать заглавную букву I и на вашем примере вы можете убедиться в полезности такой практики - в описании класса сразу видно что есть что.

Comment: Абсолютно верно